# Upgrading Visual Studio 2013 to 2017, how to deploy Crystal Report reports

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I developed a `WinForm` application with `Visual Studio 2013` that uses a lot of `Crystal Report` report created with `CrystalReport for Visual Studio 2013` (CRforVS_13_0_12).

Now I would like to update my IDE to `Visual Studio 2017` with the new `CrystalReport for Visual Studio 2017` (CRforVS_13_0_12) since the old version of CR doesn't work on VS2017.

My application is deployed via `ClickOnce`, what's the best way to deploy the updated application with the new CR reference ?

Do I need to run the new setup from the deploy folder in every client ?